# remapping json, for google charts.PHP json

Tags: php

Hi this is json format accepted with google charts.

```
  {
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

this is my foreach values of an array

15:00:00"actual value$"89.8599"actual time"2018-02-06 14:55:00"actual value$"89.6500"actual time"2018-02-06 14:50:00"actual value$"88.9650"actual time"2018-02-06 14:45:00"actual value$"88.7200"actual time"2018-02-06 14:40:00"actual value$"88.6600"actual time"2018-02-06 14:35:00"actual value$"88.2400"actual time"2018-02-06 14:30:00"actual value$"88.2000"actual time"2018-02-06 14:25:00"actual value$"88.1800"actual time"2018-02-06 14:20:00"

this is the api response in json not full but u get the idea of how its formateed.

```
{
"Meta Data": {
"1. Information": "Intraday (5min) prices and volumes",
"2. Symbol": "MSFT",
"3. Last Refreshed": "2018-02-07 16:00:00",
"4. Interval": "5min",
"5. Output Size": "Compact",
"6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (5min)": {
"2018-02-07 16:00:00": {
"1. open": "90.1200",
"2. high": "90.2150",
"3. low": "89.5700",
"4. close": "89.6100",
"5. volume": "4596497"
},
"2018-02-07 15:55:00": {
"1. open": "90.2100",
"2. high": "90.3800",
"3. low": "89.9300",
"4. close": "90.1250",
"5. volume": "769761"
},
"2018-02-07 15:50:00": {
"1. open": "90.6200",
"2. high": "90.6299",
"3. low": "90.1100",
"4. close": "90.2000",
"5. volume": "614444"
},
"2018-02-07 15:45:00": {
"1. open": "90.5400",
"2. high": "90.7550",
"3. low": "90.5400",
"4. close": "90.6200",
"5. volume": "613032"
},
```

So aniways, im familiar with json decode so i can work with json in 
php.
But im stuck on this assignment. how to supply a json accepted format to 
google charts.
I would be very thankful im somebody can guide me in howto remap json
Or how to think to get it right, 
Im anithing that helps is good